# There a way to search all bundle'd gems project directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

This comes up occasionally. Suppose I have some strange error like an image timing out pinging some external server. The file doesn't exist in my project, and most assuredly is being called from one of my gems, but I'm not sure *which*.

Is there a way to `find all` and look through all the bundled gems all at once?

*small note:* I use Sublime as my editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bundle show --paths` gives you a list of gem paths in your project. You can then feed that list to grep or ack. See the instructions from the maintainer of Bundler in [Hack your bundle for fun and profit](http://andre.arko.net/2013/05/10/hack-your-bundle-for-fun-and-profit/).

Comment: The provided link is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command `gem server`from with in a project, navigate to

```
  http://localhost:8808/
```

in your browser. I think you may find what your looking for.

Comment: Wow! Nitto mosquito. Not *exactly* what I'm looking for but +1 anyway for me never having heard of this. What I'm looking for specifically is a .png asset that a gem is calling, but I'm not entirely sure which gem is calling it..